# Get the unique data of td with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to get the data of the selected td items. In this case say I want the data of second `<td>` item from each row. I tried a simple Jquery to get the HTML, but it would get the same data (i.e the data from the first `<tr>` -> second `<td>`. How do i get the data from second row and the consecutive row.

### EDIT

I want to get the data (the text of td) when the respective link is clicked.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td class="name">First</td>
  <td>something else</td>
  <td><a class="link">Order</a></td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td class="name">second</td>
  <td>something else</td>
  <a class="link">Order</a>

</tr>
</table>
```

The functions I used would simply get the data from first td with that class  only. I think I need to use something like `parent()`. But I have very little knowledge of Jquery.

```
var itemName = $('td.itemname').html();
```

or

```
var itemName = $('.itemname').html();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "data" exactly?

Comment: the content of the td.. `<td> first </td>` I mean "First"

Comment: And what output do you expect/want? By 'data' you mean 'text,' then?

Comment: ya I want the text portion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tdValues = [];
$(".name").each(function () {
    tdValues.push($(this).text());
});
```

Now you have an array of the text content of each `td` in the variable `tdValues`.

If you *only* want the second row:

```
var tdValue = $("tr:eq(1) .name").text();
```

If you want the second row and on,

```
$("tr:gt(0) .name").each(...)
```

EDIT:

```
$(".link").on('click', function () {
    var text = $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').text();
});
```

Comment: I have made some changes to the question.. sorry..for late changes

Comment: Why not simply: `var arrayName = $(".name").map(function(){ return $(this).text(); }).get().join();`

Comment: ya.. thank you very much . it worked.
I am new to Jquery.. so every small problem causes a lot of trouble for me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want this to work when you click a link, then:

```
$(function(){
  $("a.link").click(function() {
    var secondTd = $(this).parents("tr").find("td.name").first();
    alert(secondTd.html());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nth` function like this:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(2)').text();
```

This will give you the text of all of the second columns. the `nth` function is not zero-based.